# Evento de botão com asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

eu crio um botao em asp.net, coloco onclick"testeBotao", e aperto f7, mas não carrega o evento, apenas o pageLoader.
Como faço para capturar o evento?

Comment: Você sabia que você pode votar nas respostas que lhe dão? Eu percebi que você não vota. Aceitar uma resposta não é a única forma de recompensar quem lhe ajudou. O voto pode ser dado em todas as respostas e e perguntas do *site* que você acha que merece. Não só nos seus *posts*. Mas especialmente em respostas para você seria legal você votar em todas que ajudaram de alguma forma. Lembrando que aceitação só pode uma, mas voto pode em todas que quiser. Não estou dizendo para votar em respostas que não ajudaram em nada. Se puder revise todas suas perguntas e vote nas respostas úteis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao digitar o `OnClick=""` você pode apertar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Espaço</kbd> dentro das aspas e selecionar `<Create New Event>`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o seu método será criado no code-behind.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

`onclick="btnMeuBotao_Click"` e não `onclick"testeBotao"`

e no behind faça:

```
protected void btnMeuBotao_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{....}
```